# Heap: lowest value greater than a certain value

Tags: python, heap

I've been looking at this too long and can't see the wood for the trees. It's my first time looking at heaps in Python and I can't quite work out how to put in a condition to get the value I need.

I have a list of tuples which is passed into a function.

```
reqs = [(1, 4), (2, 5), (5, 8)]
myFunc(reqs)
```

in the function I heapify it, then pop the first tuple off and store its second value, the 'end time'.

```
def myFunc(requests):
    heapq.heapify(requests)
    while(len(requests) != 0):       
        endTime = heapq.heappop(requests)[1]
```

I then want to get the next value that satisfies the condition where the first digit in the tuple is greater than the endTime. 4 is the end time. So the first value that satisfies the condition is (5,8) as 5 is greater than 4, so this is the one I want to pop off next.

I have tried nSmallest with a key but can't get that to work. I can tried looping up through the heap to find and element that fits my condition but then how do I pop that element? I'm sure it's a basic problem but I need help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You really can't do anything with values in a heap other than the first one, as nothing else will be in a particular position - looping through the heap is a meaningless operation.  If I'm understanding your requirements correctly, each time you choose an item from the heap, you'd have to pop (and ignore) additional items until you reach one with a start time greater than the chosen item's end time.

Comment: I would say that you are using the wrong tool here. `heapq` uses a *queue* so you can only pop the smallest element in natural order.

Comment: Okay, thanks all. Back to the drawing board. I'm trying to complete a challenge on Codewars. I wrote an answer that works but it's too slow for bigger inputs so it was rejected. Trying to find a more efficient way and it suggested priority queues so I thought I wanted a heap. Time to try again!! (again).

Comment: If the underlying data structure allows indexed assignment (i.e. if it's a list and not a queue), then I suspect you can remove an arbitrary node from the heap and rearrange the remaining nodes to satisfy the usual invariants in O(log n) time. The real problem is locating the node you want to remove. Binary heaps are only partially ordered, so finding a node within a particular range will probably be O(N) or so. If you're doing this a lot, then it won't necessarily be more efficient than keeping your data in a regular list.